# запись аудио не создает аудио файл

Tags: flutter, dart

Для записи аудио я использую плагин **audio_recorder 1.0.2**
[audio_recorder 1.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_recorder)

Добавил разрешения, скопировал код, изменил путь, запустил на телефоне. Все вроде выполняется, судя по скриншотам, но выходного аудио файла файла нет. У кого-то была такая проблема? Далее, полный код и скришоты. На скриншоте виден путь, но файла нет.

***main.dart***

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:audio_recorder/audio_recorder.dart';
import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:file/local.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
   home: new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
     title: new Text('Plugin audio recorder'),
    ),
    body: new AppBody(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class AppBody extends StatefulWidget {
 final LocalFileSystem localFileSystem;

 AppBody({localFileSystem})
  : this.localFileSystem = localFileSystem ?? LocalFileSystem();

 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new AppBodyState();
}

class AppBodyState extends State<AppBody> {
 Recording _recording = new Recording();
 bool _isRecording = false;
 Random random = new Random();
 TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

 String _str = '';

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Center(
   child: new Padding(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: new Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
     children: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(
       onPressed: _isRecording ? null : _start,
       child: new Text("Start"),
       color: Colors.green,
      ),
      new FlatButton(
       onPressed: _isRecording ? _stop : null,
       child: new Text("Stop"),
       color: Colors.red,
      ),
      new TextField(
       controller: _controller,
       decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Enter a custom path',
       ),
      ),
      new Text("File path of the record: ${_recording.path}"),
      new Text("Format: ${_recording.audioOutputFormat}"),
      new Text("Extension : ${_recording.extension}"),
      new Text("Audio recording duration : ${_recording.duration.toString()}"),
      Text('_str: $_str'),
     ]),
   ),
  );
 }

 _start() async {
  try {
   if (await AudioRecorder.hasPermissions) {
    if (_controller.text != null && _controller.text != "") {
     String path = _controller.text;
     if (!_controller.text.contains('/')) {
      //io.Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      io.Directory appDocDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      path = appDocDirectory.path + '/' + _controller.text;
      _str = appDocDirectory.path;
     }
     print("Start recording: $path");
     await AudioRecorder.start(
      path: path, audioOutputFormat: AudioOutputFormat.AAC);
    } else {
     await AudioRecorder.start();
    }
    bool isRecording = await AudioRecorder.isRecording;
    setState(() {
     _recording = new Recording(duration: new Duration(), path: "");
     _isRecording = isRecording;
    });
   } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
     new SnackBar(content: new Text("You must accept permissions")));
   }
  } catch (e) {
   print(e);
  }
 }

 _stop() async {
  var recording = await AudioRecorder.stop();
  print("Stop recording: ${recording.path}");
  bool isRecording = await AudioRecorder.isRecording;
  File file = widget.localFileSystem.file(recording.path);
  print("  File length: ${await file.length()}");
  setState(() {
   _recording = recording;
   _isRecording = isRecording;
  });
  _controller.text = recording.path;
 }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы сам пример пробовали запускать, он работает или нет?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в пути или разращения на запись. Посмотрите через отладку кода.

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, а скриншоты я откуда взял? Конечно запускал. ВСЕ ДЕЛО ВОТ В ЧЕМ. ЗАПУСТИТЬ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ, СОЗДАТЬ ФАЙЛ (ПОКА ЕГО НЕ ВИДНО). ОТСОЕДИНИТЬ USB КАБЕЛЬ ТЕЛЕФОНА. ОПЯТЬ СОЕДИНИТЬ КАБЕЛЬ ТЕЛЕФОНА. ПОСЛЕ ЭТОГО ФАЙЛ ВИДЕН !!! Такие вот нюансы в программировании...